# Will ESM patches eventually be shared with the community?

Tags: updates, esm

I think I understand the basic mechanics of the ESM service, but what the patches Canonical provides are unclear. I can imagine 2 scenarios under the release ESM model, and wonder which (if either) it is.  Is it,

1. Canonical will create fixes, but only share them with 'Ubuntu Pro' users, rather than share them with the broader community.  (which is presumably allowed under the various licenses)?
2. Alternatively, is it just that Canonical will build mainstream code into `.deb` packages and make these available?
3. Something else?

If it is 1., will Canonical's security patches eventually be shared with the original software developers or the broader community?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a combination of (1) and (2), and esm sources are already available on esm.ubuntu.com/

Comment: "*will Canonical's security patches eventually be shared with the original software developers...?*" Many patches come from the upstream developers already. Patches that are written by the Ubuntu Security Team are not kept secret. They are shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security patches to packages in the `main` repository are shared with everybody immediately via the <release>-security repository.

- Example: A patch to `Foo 1.1` (jammy/main)
  will show up as `Foo 1.1-1ubuntu0` (jammy/jammy-security) **Everybody**

Security patches to packages in the `universe` repository are shared 1) Immediately to Pro subscribers, and 2) Everybody in the next release of Ubuntu.

- Example: A patch to `Bar 1.1` (jammy/universe)
  will show up as `Bar 1.1-1ubuntu0` (jammy/esm-apps) **Pro Only**
  and also in the next release of Ubuntu as `Bar 1.2 (mantic/universe)` **Everybody**

Alternately, if any community member is willing to spend the time applying security patches to a `universe` package, then any MOTU can upload it, and it can be available for everybody in <release>-updates/universe. This is the historic method and it's still available for anybody willing. The problem is simply that too few volunteers are willing.

- Example: A patch to `Baz 1.1` (jammy/universe)
  will show up as `Baz 1.1-1ubuntu0` (jammy-updates/universe) **Everybody**