Ubuntu Pro: How does the updating process work?
Ubuntu and its flavors (Lubuntu, etc.) now have a Pro feature (free for personal use) that provide security patches for basically all common software (over 20,000 packages), for several years in long-term support releases.
I’m not sure how it works though. It sounds like there’s a team of developers paid by Canonical that will try to fix security bugs as soon as possible, providing patches faster than the original software developers or the original repo maintainers. If so, then Ubuntu might have become significantly more secure than other free distros.
However it all depends on how this Pro feature actually works. For example, if the Canonical team just waited for the official patches from the original developers, then the overall security would be equivalent to that of a rolling release distro (basically achieving rolling-release security on a fixed-release LTS distro).
So the question is: how does this Pro feature work in Ubuntu, and how does it compare with the security of other free distributions, in terms of security updates?

A 3rd party patching software on behalf of the official dev teams? Sounds like a nightmare to me. And you are asking about the impact of your imagined definition of the service before you actually know what the service does. Let's first figure out what "Pro" means ...

For a close look at exactly how the Ubuntu Security Team works, and how their work is integrated into public CVE disclosure, try their Ubuntu Security Podcast. 238 episodes, so far, of examples and good learning.

This question is similar to: What are ESM Apps, and how do they relate to Ubuntu Pro?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Basically they're going to backport patches. That's hard enough without having create patches from scratch.

@schroeder, there's a reason though why this was asked on security.stackexchange (and with a different title): I'd also like to understand how this compares to other distro's security update policies. In other words I'd like to know if this Pro feature makes Ubuntu more secure than Debian for example, or just as secure as Debian. Because if it's just as secure as Debian, then it would mean that Ubuntu without the Pro subscription (although it's free) would have been made insecure on purpose by avoiding patching.

@muru, it is different, but the title has been edited by moderators and the question migrated from security.se. See my comment above.

What metric are we supposed to use to determine if distro A is "just as secure" as distro B?

@user535733, I said "in terms of security updates", so based on how the repos are maintained.

For "how the repos are maintained",  please review https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477351/ . If that does not answer your question, then please clarify.


It sounds like there’s a team of developers paid by Canonical that will try to fix security bugs as soon as possible, providing patches faster than the original software developers or the original repo maintainers.

There is a team of professional security engineers paid by Canonical on the Ubuntu Security Team.
Among many other things, that team handles both public and private CVE reports, and handles the directly-related patching and testing.

Security-related bugs (including CVEs) are triaged and prioritized by the Ubuntu Security Team.
However, the implicit assumption that ALL security-related bugs must be high-priority is false. Many are not: Hard to implement, require special conditions, limited effectiveness, etc. Ubuntu does not promise that lower-priority security issues will get addressed "as soon as possible." Some may await the next release of Ubuntu.

The usual workflow is to use the upstream-provided patches, which are typically included with many CVEs. Then the patch must be tested by the Team. The Team can create their own patches, but that effort tends to consume a lot of resources so it's not their first choice.

Critical security CVEs may sometimes be shared confidentially (delayed public disclosure) among many organizations in the cases where a coordinated response will be more effective.
Ubuntu does not promise to break confidentiality by releasing patches earlier.


All of these activities are in line with the best practices of peer organizations.
Ubuntu promises to be stable and secure, as do other distros with professional security engineers on staff. Ubuntu does not promise to be "significantly more secure" (whatever that might mean).

What does "upstream" here refer to? It could mean the repos (which are maintained by the community), or it probably means directly from the original projects (maintained by original devs). In either case, quick patches are not guaranteed (if at all), but Ubuntu Pro claims to be able to patch in about 1 day on average. How does that work?

"upstream" typically refers to the project that develops the affected code, though it could (rarely) refer to a patch created by a third party like another distro or other organization. Example: Patches to openssh usually come from the upstream openssh project developers.

For specific questions about Ubuntu Pro performance and promises, you must ask Canonical. Ubuntu Pro is a Canonical product, not an Ubuntu service. AskUbuntu volunteers have no special insight into the Pro product, and AskUbuntu volunteers are not affiliated with Canonical.
